# Limit Event Handler

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port, port, eventhandler

Apologies if my 'lingo' doesn't make sense... I'm fairly new to this and coding!

I am working on a project which involves a RFID reader and a Bluetooth module communicating with a C# windows form.

The com port event handler sends the RFID tag's unique ID continuously. Is there a way for it to be sent just once?

Is there a way for the program to just receive the ID once, so it can be processed; as opposed to receiving the ID numerous times.

Thanks in advance! :)

My code so far is as follows.

I have the serial port open from somewhere else

```
private void port_DataRecieved(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataRecievedEventArgs e) 
{
    string data = serialPort.ReadExisting(); // read what came from the RFID reader

    if (data.Length > 9) // check if the string if bigger than 9 characters
    {
        CODE = data.Substring(0, 9); // if string is bigger than 9 characters trim the ending characters until it is only 9 long
    }
    else
    {
        CODE = data; // if less that 9 characters use however many it gets
    }
}
```

Comment: If your question, is mainly about trying to control the event handler behavior, you should probably put that in the title.  I also suggest making your question stand out more, like by putting it at the top or bottom of your question.

Comment: Configure the reader so you can use ReadLine() instead, tweak the NewLine property as necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `ReadExisting`.  Instead check whether there are 9 bytes yet.

If not, return immediately.

If yes, read only 9 and leave the others for the next event.

You probably should have some resynchronization logic also.

Also, received data needs to be in a `byte[]`, not a string.  The Microsoft-provided serial port class always leads people to use the wrong approach.